# Controller unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Как это сделать, если я зажимаю влево потом зажимаю вправо - он идет вправо,
если я зажимаю вправо потом зажимаю влево - он идет влево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string LastButton = "a";
public Rigidbody2D rb;

void FixedUpdate(){
    if (LastButton == "A" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(5, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    if (LastButton == "D" && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-5, rb.velocity.y);
    }
 }

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            LastButton = "A";
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            LastButton = "D";
        }
}
```